# Android facebook sso - Invalid token

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am new to facebook sso, i have integrated the SSO into my application, this works fine in android emulator, at the same time when i do this application on device, am facing the error..  shows that invalid_token , but the same thing is working in emulator. i really don't know where the mistake is.

Even i have created the keystore and mapped with facebook apps and secret id...

Still the problem is not getting resolved...

please guide me to solve this particular issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some details about what you have done so far. And also, if you have logcat info about the error/s, that will make it easier to figure out the problem. But not without seeing the code you have used. Post some.

Comment: I am using phone gap(cordova), in the same application i can able to post FB wall, and moreover the same application works through emulator. But when i pack into device apk, it wont. is there anything we have to do it on facebook settings.

Comment: Please add the info about you using the **phonegap** platform. And again, without code, not much advise can be offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the SSO, the errors that are caused vary, but are probably all connected to the problem facebook is having.
It has been acknowldged by facebook as you can is in the [Platform Status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status) page.

It works in the emulator since you probably don't have the android facebook application installed on the emulator, because of that the SSO process is not the one which is used but the auth process that ships with the fb android sdk.

If the fb application is installed then the SSO kicks in and then that bug gets in the way.
There's no way to solve this for now (as far as I'm aware), the only thing is to "not using the SSO" even if it's available.
Other than that it's just waiting for facebook to solve the problem (though it has been like this for about a week or so already).

Comment: That was a few days back and the problem has been solved already. The same link clearly shows that the Android SSO issue is now resolved....

Comment: It says that it was resolved 4 days ago, but still we had issues with it yesterday. I still consider that issue to be a **possible** reason for SSO problems, and I thought it might help to share.

Comment: You sure it is not a one off case with the issue you are facing? I am working on FB integration in one of my apps and have been testing like crazy the last few days with a few beta testers as well. Not one problem reported since they sorted it out.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, the code that works on the emulator, the same code that works well when the facebook application is removed from the device, does not work on a device that has the fb application on it. The SSO code itself was not changed and used to work well.

Comment: All seems to be fine here. Did have an issue which we thought was the SSO playing up again. Turned out we had the wrong key hash in our FB App settings. Same symptoms as reported by the OP and you.

Comment: That's irrelevant, I wasn't asking a question, was just offering a possibility, one you disagree with, this discussion is really pointless.

Comment: No problem fella. Relax. No intention to start a flame war here.